# How could I force the data type of a computed column to a bit field that don't allow nulls?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I got a computed column that I need to be a bit field, here an example of formula :

```
case when ([some_field] < [Some_Other_field]) 
then 0 
else 1 
end
```

The data type of computed column set using this formula is `int`.

What's the best way to force the correct data type?

With a `CONVERT` statement on the whole case, data type is `bit` but it `Allow Nulls`

```
CONVERT([bit], 
        case when (([some_field] < [Some_Other_field]) 
        then 0 
        else 1 
        end,
        0)
```

Same thing with a `CONVERT` statement on the result expressions, data type is `bit` but it `Allow Nulls`

```
case when (([some_field] < [Some_Other_field]) 
then CONVERT([bit], (0), 0) 
else CONVERT([bit], (1), 0) 
end
```

Or there is a smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wrap the computed column definition in [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx), with whatever you like as the second argument (provided it's a bit, or convertible to such).

This is one of the few places where you have to use `ISNULL` rather than (the generally better designed) [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx). SQL Server has special case logic to realise that an `ISNULL` with a non-null second argument represents a non-nullable result.

E.g.:

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(bit,case when ([some_field] < [Some_Other_field]) 
then 0 
else 1 
end),0)
```

This can also be used in e.g. view definitions.

Comment: Do you or anyone has an idea if there are performance differences between your example and the following alternative syntax: `case when ([some_field] < [Some_Other_field]) 
then ISNULL(CONVERT(bit,0),0) 
else ISNULL(CONVERT(bit,1),1) 
end`?

Comment: @tomosius - I wouldn't expect a *measurable* difference in the grand scheme of things (e.g. I/O costs related to data access and network overheads). I'd also suspect that your variant may reintroduce the very issue that the question sought to avoid - that `CASE` expressions are frequently analysed as potentially being NULLable even though by inspection we know it cannot.

Answer (score 12):

If you persist the computed column you can specify `not null`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx

```
CONVERT([bit], 
        case when (([some_field] < [Some_Other_field]) 
        then 0 
        else 1 
        end,
        0) PERSISTED NOT NULL
```